# Pegar posição atual do celular pelo Location

Tags: java, android

Pessoal estou tentando fazer um app para rastrear o celular (pegar a posição atual do mesmo), o problema é que eu não sei como fazer.

Eu preciso que o celular pegue sua posição atual (longitude e latitude) sem usar o GPS preciso que o app se baseie nas redes Wi-Fi disponíveis, eu acho que ele pega a posição vendo quais redes Wi-Fi estão ao alcance e com isso ele consegue se achar, acho que tem que usar a API do Google de Geolocalização, eu não sei bem certo como que funciona isso, preciso pegar o Location do celular sem usar GPS.